# How to update widget tree from another widget class - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, statefulwidget

I am facing problem to re-render the page when a variable changes in one class/widget (both parent and child widgets are stateful classes).

Here is how it goes:
I have three buttons in one class which changes a variable state (**foodCategory**).

```
int foodCategory = 0;
// down in the elevated button body - i am updating the variable
setState(() {
          foodCategory = 1;});
```

While in the other widget, i am using this variable to perform certain actions:

```
for (var item in foodItems.values.elementAt(foodCategory))
                GestureDetector(........ and so on...
```

However in the second snippet, the widget dose not know if there has been a change and it is not calling the buildcontext again...
I am not sure how to overcome this problem. I have tried **valuelistenablebuilder** but in vain. Maybe i dont know how to use it in the loop (i am using foodcategory as an int (iterator)).

Comment: you should use GETX, in getx you can update any widget using same controller

Comment: Please share code that shows where do you use this `for` loop. If it is within the build method of the class that has `foodCategory` as member, `setState` should update. If it is in a different widget, you can do it for example with `Provider` and `Consumer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happned to be that i was sing valuelistenable builder in a wrong way.

It is easy. Just mark the variable and changes as valueNotifier. In my case, i needed to mark foodCategory as a valueNotifer.

Than, i needed to wrap the Widget (in my case column widget) as ValueListenableBuilder. This solved my issue.